# create account with my stackoverflow credentials

Tags: discussion, login

I accidentally created my account with a google credential and now do not have any reputation - not even to put this onto meta :-(

Can some moderate please correct and link it to my  stackoverflow credentials (user TaW) this so I get the usual 100 points..?

tia, tw

Comment: Simply sign out, forget this account, and sign in again with your SO credentials?

Comment: [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://askubuntu.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: @vir I tried but it offered the same google credentials, not the choice of all sorts.

Answer (score 3):

Merging requires you to use the Contact Us form at the bottom of the page to get staff to do it.  Moderators cannot merge your accounts.  See the note in the help center about merging accounts: https://askubuntu.com/help/merging-accounts

> #### I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?
>
> If you have two accounts that you would like to join together, please
> sign into either account, visit the [Contact](https://askubuntu.com/contact) form, select "Account
> Issue", and then select "[I need to merge user profiles](https://askubuntu.com/contact?topic=4)". After
> you contact us, the Stack Exchange Team will reach out to verify that
> you own both accounts. If we can confirm your ownership, we will
> initiate a merge.
>
> If you can't remember how to log in, [go here](https://askubuntu.com/users/account-recovery) and enter the email
> address you used to create the account you are trying to sign into.